# Angular doesn't show JavaScript errors on Console

Tags: javascript, angular, console

I don't know what happened but from someday I cannot see any javascript error on console.

If the page is blank for some javascript error I need to put a breakpoint on that Angular function to see which is the error.

```
function getDebugContext(error) {
return (/** @type {?} */ (error))[ERROR_DEBUG_CONTEXT];
```

}

Comment: what is the version of angular?

Comment: Anglar 5.2.0. But in compiler I have ~5.2.0 and in compiler-cli ^5.2.9

Comment: Ok. Give me some time.i'll post an answer.

Answer (score 10):

please create a .ts file called GlobalErrorHandler.ts and paste this

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ErrorHandler, Injectable, Injector } from '@angular/core';
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler implements ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) { }
  handleError(error) {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);
    console.log(error.stack.toString());

  }

}
```

Import this to your app.module.ts provider

```
providers: [

    {
      provide: ErrorHandler,
      useClass: GlobalErrorHandler
    }
  ],
```

this should work.

Comment: Thanks! It works. I changed console.log for console.error

Comment: I've come here regarding this article: https://medium.com/@kamrankhatti/angular-lazy-routes-loading-chunk-failed-42b16c22a377
because I've implemented the global error handler but there isn't mentioned that all erros will be obscured by implementing that ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
Thanks @Asanka

Comment: Why are we injecting the `Injector` and getting a reference to the router?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Injectable()
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    super();
  }

  handleError(error: any): void {
    const router = this.injector.get(Router);

    if (error.message.includes('Loading chunk')) {
      console.error('There was a problem loading a chunk:', error);
      window.location.reload();
    } else {
      super.handleError(error);
    }
  }
}
```

if you extend the ErrorHandler class, you have access to the default error handling behavior provided by Angular’s ErrorHandler class. You can override the handleError method to provide your own error handling logic, and you can call super.handleError(error) to fall back to the default behavior.

That not obscured all erros